# How can I place my Django/Celery periodic tasks and regular tasks in separate files?

Tags: python, django, celery, code-organization, django-celery

All my celery tasks are contained under a `tasks.py` under each Django app of mine. It's quite cluttered.

I'd like to move my celery periodic tasks into a `check.py` file under each app maainly to make it easier to organise and manage my code.

Is there a provision in django-celery to do this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Celery have special configuration settings named: `CELERY_IMPORTS`. Its a list with files named which need to be imported and checked for existing Celery task functions. So, i think django-celery just add there something like `*/tasks.py`.
In your way you can add somethings in footer of your manage.py script in put in `CELERY_IMPORTS` scripts what you want to use.